# getting nil while converting response to json using dict

Tags: ios, json, swift

currently i am working with login.Using api to get the response from server.i am getting successfull response from api.i am not able to parse the response that i got.

**login.swift**

```
 func convertToDictionary(text: String) -> [String: Any]? {
    if let data = text.data(using: .utf8) {
        do {
            return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    return nil
}

 let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            let dict = self.convertToDictionary(text: responseString!)
            print("DICT::", dict as Any)


            let Messaage = dict?["message"] as! String
            print("MESSAGE", Messaage)

            let Status = dict?["status"] as! String
            print("STATUS", Status)

            self.BackEndStatus = Status

           let user = dict?["user"]as?[[String : AnyObject]]
                          print(user)
```

i can print status and message bt i am not able print the user.i am getting user as nil.

Comment: can you provide the response you are getting.

Comment: then your dictionary shouldn't have valur for key `user` . once print whole dictionary and check!

Comment: @RakshithNandish i am getting response `DICT:: Optional(["status": 1, "user": {
    address = null;
    created = "2017-10-09 00:29:38";
    "device_id" = "<null>";
    "device_type" = "<null>";
    email = "chinju@gmail.com";
     name = Chinju;
    password = 76a531c195212d35ee109be6e131ac73;
    "phone_no" = 8086502009;
    "profile_status" = 1;
    "social_id" = "<null>";
    "social_type" = "<null>";
    "user_id" = 31;
    "user_role" = 1;
}, "message": login success])
MESSAGE login success
STATUS 1
nil
`

Comment: I think you need to use `as? [String : Any]` instead of `as?[[String : AnyObject]]`

Comment: Try changing `dict?["user"]as?[[String : AnyObject]]` to `dict?["user"]as?[String : AnyObject]`

Comment: It seems like the parameter "user" is just a string, not an array or a dictionary. Try let user = dict?["user"]as? String then print it and check what you will get.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are type casting it into an `Array` `[[]]` You have to typecast with Square brackets `[]`  that is point to a `Dictionary`

**Try to typecast with Square brackets:**

```
let user = dict?["user"] as? Dictionary<String,Any>
```

**Your response is:**

```
[
  "status": 1,
  "user": {
    address=null;
    created="2017-10-09 00:29:38";
    "device_id"="<null>";
    "device_type"="<null>";
    email="chinju@gmail.com";name=Chinju;
    password=76a531c195212d35ee109be6e131ac73;
    "phone_no"=8086502009;
    "profile_status"=1;
    "social_id"="<null>";
    "social_type"="<null>";
    "user_id"=31;
    "user_role"=1;
  },
  "message": loginsuccess
])
```

Answer (score 0):

The value for key `user` is a dictionary, not an array.

It's highly recommended to unwrap the optionals safely with optional bindings.

And why are you converting `Data` to `String` and then back to `Data`?

```
func convertToDictionary(data: Data) -> [String: Any]? {
    do {
       return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: Any]
    } catch {
       print(error.localizedDescription)
       return nil
    }
}
```

---

```
if let dict = self.convertToDictionary(data: data) {
    print("DICT::", dict)

    let message = dict["message"] as! String
    print("MESSAGE", message)

    let status = dict["status"] as! String
    print("STATUS", status)

    self.backEndStatus = status

    if let user = dict["user"] as? [String : Any] {
        print(user)
    }
}
```

PS: Please conform to the naming convention that variable names start with a lowercase letter